# How to add WooCommerce product content with html via rest api

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I manage to generate simple Woocommerce product over REST api.
I fail to add product content with html code (e.g. table in my case).

The rest api

```
 $api_response = wp_remote_post( $client_domain . '/wp-json/wc/v3/products', array( 
'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $K.':'.$S )
),
'body' => array(
    'name' => $product_name,        // product title
    // 'status' => 'publish',         // default: publish
    'type' => 'simple',
    'categories' => array(
        array( 
            'id' => 22       // each category in a separate array
        )
    ),
    'regular_price' => $price,      // product regular price
    'price' => $price,               // current product price
    'description' => $allTable,   // **** HTML TABLE ... *****
    'short_description' => 'tilesim user product',
    'visible' => true,        // current product price  'images' => [ ['src' => $pimage] ] // array( "src" => $pimage)
    'images' => [
                [
                    'src' => $pimage 
                ],
                [
                    'src' => $rimage 
                ]
            ]

)
```

The line with commented starts (****) has the variable (`$allTable`) that will be displayed as raw html instead of a table:

![beautified html]https://s-ivry.tilesim.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/woo_product_html.png)

How do I get over this issue and get the table, not the html markup?

Comment: while you displayed the content user htmentities

Comment: It's not associated with woocommerce, it's because of the filter `wp_trim_excerpt` applied to the WordPress post excerpt (and of course applied to the product as a post type), try to override/remove the filter to allow HTML entities

Comment: @Shahin wp_trim_excerpt has no effect on content as in [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/)
Any more ideas?

Comment: @dipmala Thanks!!! its ```html_entity_decode() ``` Works like a charm.

Comment: Then let me add the answer so you can like my answer :)

Comment: @Mulli Even I'm not referring to the function itself, I'm referring to the filter hook, But I didn't realize that your problem associated with the description, not the short description, sorry for confusing you, Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP provides the htmlentities function which are used to encode and decode. Kindly check below examples how you can decode the php strings.

```
$str = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com&quot;&gt;w3schools.com&lt;/a&gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Comment: Where would you use this with the WooCommerce REST API when adding a product description with html?